# Tablet WPF Windows Desktop Application - Scrolling issue

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, scrollview, scrollviewer

I'm running my desktop application WPF on tablet ASUS ME400 Intel Atom Z2760. All working properly, but when I use scrollviewer, scroll movement with finger (abilitate panning mode horizontalOnly) at the end of scroll with finger, the window moves and you see the taskbar for a moment. The effect is not seen if I scroll with my finger, did not arrive until founded in the scrollbar.

How i can avoid this window movement? How I can lock my windows and do not permit to move when I scroll at the end of scrollbar?

Answer (score 11):

In the `ScrollViewer` object, where you've enabled the panning, register a new event for `ManipulationBoundaryFeedback`.

```
<ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="ScrollViewer_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback">
    <!-- your content is here... -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

In the codebehind, you have to handle the event, by setting the `Handled` property to `true`:

```
void ScrollViewer_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

*(By setting the `Handled` property to `true`, we are actually telling that the event has got handled by us, so we are stopping the message's bubbling process in the Visual Tree, before it would reach the `Window`/`Application` - whichever would cause the shaking.)*