# WPF Scrollviewer on touch screen tablet

Tags: wpf, windows-8, scrollviewer, touchscreen

I'm writing a WPF application that is going to run on a full windows 8 touchscreen tablet (not RT).

However touch scrolling doesn't seem to be working. So I'm wondering if it's something I'm doing wrong or if it's even possible?

So, I have a WPF window with a scrollviewer. Within that scrollviewer I have a StackPanel which has loads of textblocks within it. See below:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Row 1" />
            <TextBlock Text="Row 2" />
            <TextBlock Text="Row 3" />
            <TextBlock Text="Row 4" />
            <TextBlock Text="Row 5" />
            <TextBlock Text="Row 6" />
            ....
            <TextBlock Text="Row 50" />                
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Now using the touchscreen I try to scroll the contents but it doesn't move. I can only scroll the contents using side scollbar which is not how I want this to work. Is it possible to get touch scrolling working with WPF? I'd also want to do the same with the grid.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Visual Studio/Blend 2012.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can enable scrolling with the `PanningMode` property like this:
`<ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both"></ScrollViewer>`.

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode.aspx/)

**Mouse support**

If you want to implement this behavior with the mouse, please read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37349/Creating-A-Scrollable-Control-Surface-In-WPF.aspx).

Comment: Know how to enable this with the mouse?

Comment: If you have the **"shaking window"** problem, when the scrollbar reaches it's end, check the following solution: [Shaking Window Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126400/tablet-wpf-windows-desktop-application-scrolling-issue/37000344#37000344)